# How to validate Multiple Methods using JSON/XSD validator in WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I need to validate in-coming JSON request structure in WSO2 I was able to do that but there are 2 different methods GET and POST in the same context so  validation applies to both the methods but I dont need validation for GET method. How to restrict validation for only one method. 
I applied filters but it was not working can someone help me on how to achieve this.
Tool: WSO2 API manger 2.6.0.

I am trying with below code but unable to publish it. Please help me on this.

```
    <property name="Resource" expression="get-property('axis2', 'REST_URL_POSTFIX')"/>
<property name="requestMethod" expression="get-property('axis2', 'HTTP_METHOD')"/>
<filter source="$ctx:Resource" regex="/books">
    <filter source="$ctx:requestMethod" regex="POST">
        <than>
            <validate>  
                <schema key="conf:/LocalBkStore.json"/>     
                    <on-fail>
                        <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                            <format>...</format>
                            <args>
                                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:ERROR_MESSAGE"/>
                            </args>
                        </payloadFactory>
                        <property name="HTTP_SC" value="500" scope="axis2"/>
                        <respond/>
                    </on-fail>      
            </validate>
        <than>      
    </filter>
</filter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can achieve by adding a custom in-flow sequence in `<apim-home>/repository/resources/customsequences/in` as below,

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"  name="detect_get_post">      
<property name="requestURL" expression="get-property('axis2', 'REST_URL_POSTFIX')"/>
<property name="requestMethod" expression="get-property('axis2', 'HTTP_METHOD')"/>
<filter source="$ctx:requestURL" regex="/books">
    <then>
        <filter source="$ctx:requestMethod" regex="POST">
            <then>
                //POST request having the URL path /books and you can do the validation here
            </then>
        </filter>
    </then>
</filter>
```

You can copy and paste the above code snippet and add the validation part where I have added a comment.

In the code snippet you have added, after the first `filter` mediator there should be a `then` tag and also there is a spelling mistake in the `then` tag of second `filter` mediator.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have updated my question with the code can you please look into it and suggest where is the fault in my code.

Comment: I updated the answer reflecting to your code snippet

Comment: Can you upvote and select it as the correct answer?

Comment: Marked it has correct answer but dont have reputation to upvote it.